# Explain "Allow calendar.google.com to open all web calendar links?"

Tags: google-calendar, google-chrome

I've opened https://calendar.google.com in Chrome. I see an icon in the address bar. When I click on it, it displays this dialog:

> Allow calendar.google.com to open all web calendar links?
>
> [ ] Allow [ ] Deny [ ] Ignore

[image: Screenshot]

What does this feature do? What does opening a web calendar link do? Can you give me an example of a web calendar link?

**Edit:** Please note that this is *not* a duplicate of [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2603/automatically-open-ics-files-in-google-calendar), which is about Firefox, not Chrome, and which is about `.ics` files in the desktop file explorer, not web calendar links. Furthermore, the answers to that question talk about how to run JavaScript in the browser or install extensions, they do not explain what "opening all web calendar links" does.

Comment: Actually, yes, it's a duplicate, please read all the answers. More specifically read https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/36686/88163 including the comments. Also read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Calendar_Access_Protocol

Comment: @Rubén The question you linked to no longer exists. I'm not sure why. I feel bad that I wasted so much time and emotion arguing that question post was not a duplicate, only for it to be deleted after all.

Comment: @Rubén And now you go ahead and answer [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/169891/how-do-i-allow-web-calendar-links-for-goole-calendar-on-windows-10-ms-edge). Why do say that my answer should be closed, but go ahead and answer that one, a newer one?

Comment: First, I'm sorry for so many changes. The question that initially was used as the duplicate target for this question was found to be an exact copy of a question posted by the same author 10 months before in [su] -> https://superuser.com/q/44191/. It was deleted because cross-poting is not allowed across [se] sites. It might be possible to ask about the same issue on several sites but each question should be tailored according to the scope  and workings of each of them.  Also several answers were also posted on both sites, several them were obsolete and the answers that were not ...

Comment: ...was posted in SU didn't addressed what was asked. Regarding the close of a question as duplicate this is done because the target question had the answer to the question marked as duplicate. It doesn't really matter that the question title / body doesn't match exactly the duplicate. Regarding the topic both questions are about the same. At the time that the "origional" questions was deleted, the answer to the Microsoff Edge question was  already posted I opted to use that answer as a canonical answer, instead of posting slight variations of the same information in multiple answers.

Comment: OK. That makes sense that the old question was deleted because of cross-posting. Personally, I don't mind cross-posting, but that's another story. I know moderation is hard work and there aren't many volunteers in this site. I admit I was frustrated this morning. I'm sorry.